# How is fetch() different from run() in app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_fetch), I know that `Query.run()` returns an iterable and `Query.fetch()` returns a list. The docs say that `fetch()` is just a wrapper on `run()` and should generally not be used because it's more memory intensive. But from my (limited) experience they do the same thing: they let you loop over the results of your query. Why does `fetch()` exist? What is it for and what is it doing that's less efficient than `run()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run() returns an iterable that issues async calls as needed to pull data from the datastore as you iterate through your items.  If you don't iterate through your entire result set, it may not return all the entities in the result set.

fetch() essentially calls run(), iterates through the entire result set and places all the results in a list.

If you use fetch(), you'll get the list back and then iterate through it again.

fetch() tends to be beneficial in cases where you absolutely, must get all your data in a list and operate on a list.